# How altbeacon is keeping a background service alive?

Tags: android-service, altbeacon, beacon

I am running into a issue that is the opposite problem of this thread:

[AltBeacon not detect beacon when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064280/altbeacon-not-detect-beacon-when-app-is-closed)

I have an app that uses altbeacon (http://altbeacon.org/)

The app initializes the alt-beacon implementing the interfaces at the application level as below (details omitted)

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements
    BootstrapNotifier,
    BeaconConsumer {
//some code
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initBeacons();
}
public void initBeacons() {
    mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager altBeaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    altBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    // estimote
    altBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000);
    altBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(25000);
    mBeaconManager = MyBeaconManager.getInstance(this, altBeaconManager);
    mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, MyBeaconManager.getRegions());
    altBeaconManager.bind(this);
}
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        // Try range the beacons
        rangeMyBeacons();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    // Some code 
}
@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    // Some code
}
@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    // Some code    
}
public class MyBeaconManager implements
    RangeNotifier {
// some code
```

However, If I kill the app or restart the phone, without any special broadcasts or app permissions the alt-beacon service comes back alive. Alt-beacon re-starts itself all the time, in other words. Notice that I don't have any foreground services running. Here' is a screenshot of the app after several hours (and I rebooted the phone), with all apps closed. You can see the alt-beacon is alive and scanning the beacons.

[image]
yet when I look at alt-beacon code, it is not a foreground service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LogManager.i(TAG,
            intent == null ?
                    "starting with null intent"
                    :
                    "starting with intent " + intent.toString()
    );
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I did search inside the library and I see not hits to START_REDELIVER_INTENT or START_STICKY.

My question is how does alt-beacon keep the service alive when the app is killed?

The reason I want to understand this feature is that I am writing a similar service but I can only get it do work as alt-beacon if I wrap it into a foreground service. Everything else I tried, the service gets killed as soon as the app closes.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library uses an `AlarmManager` to keep the scanning service running in the background.  It periodically sets an alarm for 5 minutes in the future, which causes the operating system to deliver it a `BroadcastIntent` which will start the scanning service if stopped.  When running, the library continually reschedules this alarm.

You can see the code that does that here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/scanner/CycledLeScanner.java#L339

```
// In case we go into deep sleep, we will set up a wakeup alarm when in the background to kickoff
// off the scan cycle again
protected void setWakeUpAlarm() {
    // wake up time will be the maximum of 5 minutes, the scan period, the between scan period
    long milliseconds = 1000l * 60 * 5; /* five minutes */
    if (milliseconds < mBetweenScanPeriod) {
        milliseconds = mBetweenScanPeriod;
    }
    if (milliseconds < mScanPeriod) {
        milliseconds = mScanPeriod;
    }

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + milliseconds, getWakeUpOperation());
    LogManager.d(TAG, "Set a wakeup alarm to go off in %s ms: %s", milliseconds, getWakeUpOperation());
}
```

This design ensures that if the app needs to be terminated due to low memory, scanning will be restarted five minutes in the future.  This allows the phone time to complete the memory intensive operation, while still allowing beacon detections in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: I understand the reason for 5 minutes duration. Since mine is time critical app, I don’t want to extend beyond 1 minute. So shall I reduce the duration to 1 minute or less. Please clarify whether it will cause any impact.

Comment: You could modify this line to reduce the time: `long milliseconds = 1000l * 60 * 5; /* five minutes */`. In a lil memory situation, however. You will make the user's phone lag noticably as you are refusing to let Androud evict your app from memory when it needs it for another app it seems higher priority.